# Why doesn't this swapping function work? (swapping strings in C)

Tags: c, pointers, pass-by-reference, swap, pass-by-value

I am trying to swap 2 entries in an array of strings, but my `swap` function doesn't swap when called.

```
swap(char*, char*);

int main() {
    char *ptsr[2] = { "x", "y" };
    swap(ptsr[0], ptsr[1]);
}

swap(char *t1, char *t2) {
    char *t;
    t = t1;
    t1 = t2;
    t2 = t;
}
```

Can someone identify and explain my mistake?

Comment: If you did that with `int`, what do you think `swap(1,2);` would do?

Comment: No return type for swap?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C is strictly pass by value. You pass the values of `ptsr[0]` and `pstr[1]` to `swap`. It swaps where it keeps those two values, but that has no effect on the calling function. Consider:

```
swap (int v1, int v2)
{
    int t;
    t = v1;
    v1 = v2;
    v2 = t;
}
```

This is the same as your swap function, just using `int` instead. It should be pretty clear that if you call `swap(1,2);`, the `swap` function just puts the `2` where it was storing the `1` and vice versa, but that has no effect on anything in the caller.

Same if you do this:

```
int i = 2;
int j = 3;
swap(i,j);
```

Since all you passed to `swap` is the values `2` and `3`, it cannot affect the values of `i` and `j` by any means.

And same with your swap function if you do this:

```
char* j = "hello";
char* k = "world";
swap(j,k);
```

The function receives "hello" and "world" and swaps where it stores those two pointers. This has no effect on `j` or `k` in the caller.

C is strictly pass by value. Whatever parameters you pass to a function, the function only receives the values of.

Answer (score 1):

The function in the question only swaps the values of its argument. The arguments are copies of the array elements, so the `swap` function has no effect.

To swap the pointers in the array, you must pass their addresses and change the prototype of the swap function:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void swap(char **t1, char **t2) {
    char *t;
    t = *t1;
    *t1 = *t2;
    *t2 = t;
}

int main() {
    char *ptsr[2] = { "x", "y" };

    swap(&ptsr[0], &ptsr[1]);

    printf("pstr: { \"%s\", \"%s\" }\n", pstr[0], pstr[1]);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Functions accept their arguments by value.

That is the function `swap` (for which you forgot to specify the return type `void`)

```
void swap(char *t1, char *t2) {
    char *t;
    t = t1;
    t1 = t2;
    t2 = t;
}
```

deals with copies of values of the expressions `ptsr[0]` and  `ptsr[1]`. Chamging the copies does not influence on the original pointers.

You may imagine the function definition and its call the following way

```
swap(ptsr[0], ptsr[1]);

//...

void swap( /*char *t1, char *t2*/) {
    char *t1 = ptsr[0], *t2 = ptsr[1];
    char *t;
    t = t1;
    t1 = t2;
    t2 = t;
}
```

As you can see the variables and `ptsr[0]` and `ptsr[1]` were not be changed.

To change an object (that in particularly can have a pointer type) in a function you need to pass it to the function by reference.

In C passing by reference means passing an object indirectly through a pointer to it.

So the function `swap` will look like

```
void swap(char **t1, char **t2) {
    char *t;
    t = *t1;
    *t1 = *t2;
    *t2 = t;
}
```

and the function must be called .like

```
swap( &ptsr[0], &ptsr[1] );
```

Or as the same

```
swap(ptsr, ptsr + 1);
```

Dereferencing the pointers to pointers `t1` and `t2`  the function gets a direct access to the original pointer `ptsr[0]` and `ptsr[1]` swapping their values.